# Did google cloud have Singapore zone?

Tags: google-compute-engine, cloud-computing, cloud-hosting

Based on this link [Google Cloud Zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/zones) I know that Google Cloud only have one Zone in Changhua County, Taiwan. But some post in 2014 [Google Cloud Asia Regions](http://www.zdnet.com/article/google-fires-up-asia-pacific-region-cloud-platform/) note that there are two available datacenters in Asia: Taiwan and Singapore.

I want to launch some Google compute engine nodes in Singapore. How can I do that?

Comment: That article does not say that Google offers cloud platform services in Singapore.

Comment: Google has a datacenter in Singapore, but it's not for their cloud offerings. It's likely CDN etc. for their own services.

Comment: GCP has a Singapore zone now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29184373/google-cloud-platform-compute-engine-which-asia-region-is-nearest-to-singapore/43382114#43382114

Answer (score 1):

According to the latest google documentation, the asia regions asia-east1-[a-c] are all based in Taiwan.